# SIGSEGV when using pt::ptree::value_type for a great number of json matrices

Tags: c++, json, boost, segmentation-fault

M'm trying to parse the following json file which consists mainly of json matrices of 4 values.
I'm using boost 1.63 on a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine.

```
{ 
   "root":[ 
      { 
         "name":"test1"
      },
      { 
         "name":"test2",
         "value":{ 
            "matrices":[ 
               [ 
                  23.097432,
                  23.702008,
                  27.904633,
                  32.091423
               ],
               [ 
                  67.655115,
                  11.791152,
                  57.539848,
                  52.043283
               ],
               [ 
                  58.767643,
                  71.813496,
                  78.539024,
                  52.252256
               ],
               [ 
                  68.097432,
                  81.702008,
                  97.904633,
                  72.091423
               ]
            ]
         }
      }    
   ]
}
```

I'm using the following code :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::ifstream file("json.txt");
        std::string json_string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),

                                 (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << json_string;
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);
        for (auto &e : pt.get_child("root"))
        {
            auto name = e.second.get<std::string>("name");
            if (name == "test2")
            {
                int x = 0;
                for (pt::ptree::value_type &row : e.second.get_child("value.matrices"))
                {
                    for (pt::ptree::value_type &cell : row.second)
                    {
                        double matrix[4];
                        matrix[x] = cell.second.get_value<double>();
                        cout << matrix[x] << endl;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exc)
    {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

When I run it for 4 matrices it works great.

However when the matrices are 100  I get the following segmentation fault :

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00005566e3c630cc in boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::_---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
_cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, &std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::header (
    this=0x40364093d9663843) at /usr/local/include/boost/multi_index_container.hpp:525
525     return &*bfm_header::member;
```

When I reduce the matrices to 4 it works fine.

Since I'm new at using Boost Library , what have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is here :

```
 for (pt::ptree::value_type &row : e.second.get_child("value.matrices"))
   {
   for (pt::ptree::value_type &cell : row.second)
   {
    double matrix[4];
    matrix[x] = cell.second.get_value<double>();
    // .....
   }
    x++;
 }
```

`double matrix[4]` contains always 4 elements (in local scope ..) and you increment x (x++) out of scope. Imagine that `for (pt::ptree::value_type &row : e.second.get_child("value.matrices"))` do 10 iterations :
You will try to execute `matrix[9] = cell.second.get_value<double>();` 9>4 (size of your array) wich generate a segmentation fault (accessing array out of bounds)

Answer (score 1):

Your matrices are using space on the local call stack.

Try to making a `class` for them, which uses heap allocated data using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and/or some C++ standard [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: I assume the class is for the  boost::property_tree::ptree pt and the container for the storage of the values instead of arrays, correct? If so which is the most efficient container to store the sets of four values from speed and memory point of view in case you know. Or a vector of structs will do the job as well ?